Change score model formulation and contrasts - simultaneous inference
Suppose we would like to compare pre- and post- intervention scores for several biomarkers (please note I am aware of the change from baseline vs- ANCOVA debate but my question is not about that).
Let y denote the value of biomarker b1, b2,..., bn. Without a control group (obviously not advised*), we might construct a linear model (pseudo R code) like so:
change score ~ biomarker -1                      (model 1)
where change score (y2 - y1) is the response variable and biomarker is our single categorical independent variable. After fitting model 1, we can compute the expected ("predicted") mean change score for each biomarker and its confidence interval. Because we dropped the intercept when we parameterized the model (-1) there are as many parameters as biomarkers, each one estimating the change score.
However, we could also fit a mixed effects model to data stacked in long format like so:
y ~ time * biomarker + (1|id)       (model 2)
where time is categorical with levels pre- and post-, id is a random intercept term for each subject, and the asterisk denotes an interaction term. After fitting the model, we can compute post-hoc contrasts (difference in predicted values) of time post - pre for each biomarker. These contrasts would be equivalent to the predicted mean change score from model 1, or its estimated parameters if constructed without the intercept.
This had me thinking whether or not we need to adjust confidence intervals for simultaneous inference. In model 1, we can think of the coefficients as estimated parameters and so one might argue that we do not need to adjust for simultaneous inference. The estimated parameters are equivalent to the expected value of the response variable. Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think its typical to adjust confidence intervals of expected ("predicted") means even if we present several point estimates and their confidence intervals. We are not (hypothesis) testing for differences per se, even though the predictions are estimated differences. But in model 2, because we are performing several post-hoc comparisons, it seems to me like we should adjust for simultaneous inference as would be typical in such circumstances. Perhaps in this situation we can argue against adjusting the confidence intervals as its just a re-formulation of model 1? Or maybe we can consider each post - pre contrast as independent, even if there are lots of them?
I would greatly appreciate some thoughts / guidance on this matter
*I formulated the example above without a control group to simplify the question, but obviously this is less than ideal in reality. However, I think the problem generalizes so that we can use the difference-in-difference i.e. [post(t) - pre(t)] - [post(c) - pre(c)] as our response variable (t and c denote treatment and control respectively) for model 1 and construct the equivalent mixed model formulation in model 2.
